# Linepen, linebrush and stairs in Teechart

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, teechart

I am trying to use linepen, linebrush and stairs but I get a red wavy line under them in Delphi 2007. I guess i forgot to add a unit.
Which unit should I include.

I am trying to duplicate the popupline code from the teeoffice demo.
Thanks.
P

Answer (score 1):

The `LinePen`,`LineBrush` and `Stairs` are properties of `TCustomSeries` and descendants. They are defined in unit `Series`.

Just a comment on the red wavy lines (aka `Error Insight`). At times `Error Insight` is known to give false positives. It's better in more modern Delphi versions. Sometimes storing the project files, reopening the project or rebuilding the project makes those false positives vanish.

Comment: did not work. I added Tlineseries.linepen and that got rid of the wavy line.